# sed to pick value from one file and replace in another

Tags: string, bash, text, sed, replace

I am trying to replace a value taken from one file in another:

```
{ read -r val1
  sed -i 's! nameserver .*; *$! nameserver '$val1';!;' testfile 
} < /etc/resolv.conf
```

and then replace nameserver IP in the nginx config:

```
server {
  location {
    resolver 1.2.3.4 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;
    }
```

However I am getting following error from sed:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated`s' command`

Comment: sample data in testfile is nginx config above. Yes, I am trying to read the value (IP) from /etc/resolv.conf and replace any value after resolver (which is 1.2.3.4 on example above)

Comment: @SynRomana lots of programs have access to /etc/resolv.conf; we need to see its structure on your machine to properly answer this question.

Comment: @vintnes I am not changing anything in /etc/resolv.conf I am reading from it and it always contain line or lines containing `nameserver 1.2.3.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a shot in the dark as I don't know how your resolv.conf is configured:

```
gawk '
  NR==FNR && $1=="nameserver" {if(ns=$2) nextfile}                    #1
  NR!=FNR && $1=="resolver"   {print gensub(/[^ ]+/, ns, 2); next}    #2
  NR!=FNR                                                             #3
' /etc/resolv.conf testfile > tmp && mv tmp testfile                  #4
```

1. collect nameserver from first file
2. insert collected nameserver, preserving leading whitespace
3. print modified second file
4. test for success before file change

edit: Now requires GNU Awk: `gensub` to dynamically preserve leading whitespace, `nextfile` to skip current file once we have a nameserver

Comment: That did the trick but removed leading spaces before resolver.

Comment: @SynRomana Please see edit for cleaner, but non-POSIX solution.